# How to Check a Case in mysql - MySql

Tags: mysql

[image]i have 2 tables ,let it be tab1,tab2 i have to retrieve mark from  tab2. student_id is available in both tab1 and tab2. the value should only retrieve when student_id in tab1 and tab2 are equal. other wise show null value. plz help me to write an SQL query

[image: first one is tab2 and second is tab1]

Comment: Add us structure of both tables with some kind of your own query which failed. Else we can't improve your bad query or help you with solution of this problem.

Comment: @ KuKeC  this is my query  SELECT `c`.`student_id`,`m`.`mark` FROM `sm_student_details` `d` LEFT JOIN `sm_student_class` `c` ON d.id = c.student_id  JOIN `sm_internal_assessment_marks` `m` ON m.class_id = c.class_id  and m.student_id = c.student_id WHERE c.isActive="Y"

Comment: Use left join two fetch the record

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
Select *from tab1 t1,tab2 t2 where t1.student_id=t2.student_id;
```

Comment: I have updated query it will show all values of both table. Check now.

Answer (score 0):

Use left join to fetch record

```
SELECT * FROM tab1 LEFT JOIN tab2 ON tab1.student_id=tab2.student_id
```

Comment: Not getting mark  of students as null  that are not in tab2

Comment: Try this SELECT * FROM tab2 LEFT JOIN tab1 ON tab2.student_id=tab1.student_id

Comment: Give exact name of above table I will make query for you